# Transfer data from android phone to another server

Tags: android, connection, transfer, gprs

I have written a application for android phone (nexus1) which collects some information regularly at some intervals. Now I want to transfer the information collected to some particular server regularly using GPRS as the information is collected by phone?

Answer (score 2):

you can use very different methods for this...
some things first come to my mind:

- Internet: Website to receive data (via URL)...written in Java/EE or PHP,...
- Bluetooth: If your device is always in connection with your server, you can use this

It would help, if you would specify, how you want to have your "server" working...

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want to transfer via Internet.i want to use GPRS of the android phone for data transfer

Comment: so you may have to use my first suggestion...implementing a server (javaEE or PHP) which handles a specific request via an URL, for example http://mydomain.com/server.php?lat=123&lon=456 and open it via a httpConnection (see android api)